# In org-agenda, what is an easy way to search for headlines only?

Tags: org-agenda

In C-c a s, I can search the headlines using this regex:

```
{^\*+.*mykeyword}
```

This is a bit tedious to write every time, so is there any other, easier way? Even a wrapper for a partial search to just enter "mykeyword" would be great. What function is called here?

Also, as a bonus, any fuzzy search methods?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-c a s` ends up calling `org-search-view`. Its doc string says (among other things):

> - If the search string starts with an asterisk, search only in headlines.
> - If (possibly after the leading star) the search string starts with an
>   exclamation mark, this also means to look at TODO entries only, an effect
>   that can also be achieved with a prefix argument.
> - If (possibly after star and exclamation mark) the search string starts
>   with a colon, this will mean that the (non-regexp) snippets of the
>   Boolean search must match as full words.

So `*mykeyword` should find headlines with `mykeyword` in them (case-insensitive).

It can actually do a lot more: reading its doc string is highly recommended.

Comment: Indeed;). Thanks.